# Show an example of a finite abelian $p$-group that has $p^2 + p + 1$ subgroups of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

Show an example of a finite abelian $p$-group that has $p^2 + p + 1$ subgroups of order $p$

**My Path:** I tried with the abelian group of $\mathbb{Z}_{63}=\mathbb{Z}_{9} \times \mathbb{Z}_{7} \times \mathbb{Z}_{1}$ but I'm not sure how to say if it's an abelian group

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3$ hasn't 13 subgroups.

Comment: My guess is it should be "is there...?" or "show an example of....."

Comment: @leoli1 I don't think there is written the group is of order $\;p\;$ ,but rather that it is a $\;p\,-$ group ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I thought it said 'show that a $p$-group has ...', but it is probably meant 'show an example where...' like Randall said and how you answered it.

Comment: @leoli1 That what it says, but a $\;p\,-$ group doesn't have to be a group of order $\;p\;$ . If it is finite, it must be a group of order a power of $\;p\;$ , and if it is infinite then all its elements have order a power of $\;p\;$ ...

Comment: Of course, my original comment was meant as a counterexample to the statement 'every $p$-group has $p^2+p+1$ subgroups of order $p$', but apparently I misinterpreted the statement in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Take the elementary abelian group $\;V:=\left(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\right)^3 =\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$ .

This is also a vector space of dimension $\;3\;$ over the field $\;\Bbb F_p\cong\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$, and its subspaces are the same as its subgroups (when we flip from the group to the linear space structure or back).

Let us see how many subspaces of dimension $\;1\;$ this linear space has: for any non-zero vector $\;v\in V\;$, and there are $\;p^3-1\;$ of these, you get that Span$\,v\;$ is a linear subspace of dimension 1.

To count all the *different subspaces* of dimension $\;1\;$
(subgroups 0f order $\;p\;$), we must divide by all the non-zero multiple scalars of $\;v\;$, when $\;0\neq v\in V\;$ ...well, there you go.

The idea, of course, is for you to complete details in the above.